# Custom Javascript href selector

Tags: javascript

With jquery it's rather easy to use a selector which url starts with x. Something like that:

```
$("a[href*=#test]").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('works');
});
```

Is there equivalent to it in pure javascript? Or what would be the easiest way to do it?
I have found getElementsByName and getElementsByClassName but what about this case?

Comment: Have you tried [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)?

Comment: That's why jQuery was invented to make life easier.

Comment: Yes of course, sza, but I can't use jquery in this scenario, that is why Im looking for help :)

Comment: It's a good idea to describe which browsers you're supporting for JS. I'd really recommend dropping JS in IE6/7 if possible since their market share is so small.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) should do the trick if you don't need to support IE < 8 (http://caniuse.com/queryselector)

Comment: Thank you, didnt know about that. I will just loop through all links and find the correct one.

Comment: @BadrHari: Isn't the correct one the one with the `#test` href?

Answer (score 3):

There's no equivalent in the older Javascript spec, so you can't use `querySelectorAll`, and still support older browsers like <IE8.

What you'd have to do is use `getElementsByTagName`, and then filter the results by checking each one's `href` property.  If you check the JQuery source, I think you'll find it does just that, more or less.

---

You can always use newer features like `querySelectorAll`, and include a "polyfill" to add support for older browsers.  [Here's an example](https://gist.github.com/connrs/2724353).

```
if (!document.querySelectorAll) {
    document.querySelectorAll = function(selector) {
        var doc = document,
            head = doc.documentElement.firstChild,
            styleTag = doc.createElement('STYLE');
        head.appendChild(styleTag);
        doc.__qsaels = [];

        styleTag.styleSheet.cssText = selector + "{x:expression(document.__qsaels.push(this))}";
        window.scrollBy(0, 0);

        return doc.__qsaels;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the most reliable.

Comment: @CrazyTrain d'oh! `<` symbol broke my sentence, stupid HTML encoding.

Answer (score 1):

This article has some great information on this.
http://remysharp.com/2013/04/19/i-know-jquery-now-what/

**Pure Javascript**

```
var $ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);
Element.prototype.on = Element.prototype.addEventListener;

$('#somelink')[0].on('touchstart', handleTouch);
```

But I don't think it supports old IE and you may not be able to do the selector your desire

---

However,

If your just looking for something lightweight you can use the [sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) engine on its own, without jquery.

Only weighs 4k.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Only searches anchor tags
function getElementsByHref(href) {
    var els = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    var result = [];    
    for (i=0;i<els.length;i++) {
        if (els[i].getAttribute("href") == href) result.push(els[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `for-in`. Use a `for` loop. You're going to run into trouble because you're enumerating all properties instead of just numeric ones. Also, you may not get the same order in your `result`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with document.querySelector (or querySelectorAll)

If you want a link whose href starts with 'test' you can use -

```
document.querySelectorAll("a[href^=test]');
```

Answer (score 0):

`var hyperlinks = document.getElementsByTagName("a")` would return all hyerlinks within your document. You can then loop over those results and for each element check the value of the href attribute via `element.getAttribute("href")` and check if that string value starts with the desired string, if it does then bind a click event to that element.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this procedure:

```js
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
    if ((a[i].id && a[i].id.toLowerCase().indexOf('test') !== 0) {
        continue; // id not starts with 'test'
    }
    if (a[i].addEventListener) {
        a[i].addEventListener('click', handler, false);
    } else {
        a[i].attachEvent('onclick', handler);
    }
}

function handler(e){
    e = e || window.event; // for IE8/7 backward compatibility
    if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        event.returnValue = false; // for IE8/7 backward compatibility
    }
    alert('works');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VcVpM/19/ (code)
http://jsfiddle.net/VcVpM/19/show (result page)